# Expression not working in stringTemplate

Tags: java, stringtemplate

Hi I'm using StringTemplate version 3.2.1 and Java.

I'm passing in an ArrayList to the Stringtemplate but its not picking it up.
I want to iterate through the array depending on the number of values.

```
ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();

test.add(12334435);
test.add(12334436);
...
StringTemplate sysProperties = new StringTemplateGroup("group","locationOfTemplate").getInstanceOf("templateName");
sysProperties.setAttribute("system", "test");
```

(This will work)

```
sysProperties.setAttribute("n", test);
```

(But it seems to ignore the arrayList that is passed in.
So depending on the number of values in the array, i want to dynamically build the xml)

StringTemplate on file:

```
<data>
$if(test)$
$test:{ n |
<value>
<string>$n$</string>
</value>}$
$endif$
</data>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using ST4 syntax in ST3

```
$test:{ **n|**<-- You should use 'it' attribute to iterate - "The iterated it atribute is
set automatically"
```

[source](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/StringTemplate+cheat+sheet)